# How to create a see through button with "blurred" background in iOS 7

Tags: ios, custom-controls, customization, ios7

I am updating my app to iOS 7 and wanted to improve the UI. I want to create a see through background like Control Center. So basically I have a button, which I would like to have a see through and "blurred" background like control center. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blurring effect is not available as a public API. There are third party implementations available, such as [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView), which I can recommend.

Comment: Would my app get rejected using this API? Thanks :)

Comment: @jrturton thats so useful +1

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing to stop you using a UIToolbar.

Create a UIView as a base view with clear background, add a UIToolbar anchored to it's edges so it fills the view and then add your other controls to your base view above the toolbar.

It'll look for example like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really be using a toolbar. It's called toolbar for a reason.
One way to go would be to take a snapshot image of your background and blur it (you can use UIImage+ImageEffects category included in Apple samples to achieve consistent effect).
You can then just crop the image to desired frame and use it as a background of your button.

Are you looking to have a 'dynamic' blur effect (like in Control Center)? It's still doable, but it makes things more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create blur effects with [GUPImage Framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)  here is a full tutorial about it [iOS blur effect tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60968/ios-7-blur-effects-gpuimage). The tutorial also explains why you shouldn't use toolbar for blur effect creation